# What do you do with the metalness input when using a specular workflow?

Tags: materials

I'm working with some imported assets and trying to set them up for PBR materials. They contain a specular texture so I'm setting up the Principled BSDF following the specular workflow. However, with diffuse/specular/roughness/normal inputs all connected, the metalness input still affects the output material.

As I understand it, a specular workflow means the metalness input is not used, since the reflective properties of metals/insulators can be defined perfectly well using specular and roughness inputs. So when using a specular workflow, should the metalness value be set to some default value?

EDIT: Similarly, what should be done with the specular input when using a metalness workflow?